# E: Unable to locate package libsystemd-dev

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, devstack

i am trying to install open-stack in my machine using dev-stack, but faced this problem :

```
E: Unable to locate package libsystemd-dev
+functions-common:apt_get:1                exit_trap
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:521                  local r=100
++./stack.sh:exit_trap:522                  jobs -p
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:522                  jobs=
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:525                  [[ -n '' ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:531                  '[' -f '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:536                  kill_spinner
+./stack.sh:kill_spinner:417               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:538                  [[ 100 -ne 0 ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:539                  echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:540                  generate-subunit 1499398887 282 fail
./stack.sh: line 540: generate-subunit: command not found
```

i have tried to install this package but failed:E: can't find libsystemd-dev

but i find this package here [here](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/16.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/libsystemd-dev_229-4ubuntu4_amd64.deb.html) with ubuntu version 16.04
my distribution is  14.04.
does this make difference？

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The devstack link [devstack_latest_doc](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/)says that the latest devstack supports Ubuntu 16.04/17.04.

Few packages which are available in 16.04 are not available in 14.04 or the names of the packages are different.

I see "libsystemd-dev" is available in 16.04 and the corresponding package in 14.04 is "libsystemd-daemon-dev"